# MuleSoft Log Forwarding from On-Premise to Splunk

Tags: logging, splunk, mulesoft, mule4

I have a mulesoft on-premise standalone server and i want the applications to forward the logs to splunk , i got the splunk url ( http) with port 8088 (default one)

Url: http://:8088/services/collector/raw

and i deployed a mule app by updating the log4j2.xml under src/main/resources , on the server it throws this error

Tried to followed this article : https://dzone.com/articles/recipe-to-implement-splunk-enterprise-on-premise-f

```
ERROR 2020-07-21 11:05:48,067 [pool-58-thread-2] [event: ] com.mulesoft.agent.common.internalhandler.splunk.transport.HECTransport: There was an error executing the request.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:213) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.agent.common.internalhandler.splunk.transport.HECTransport.send(HECTransport.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.agent.common.internalhandler.AbstractSplunkInternalHandler.flush(AbstractSplunkInternalHandler.java:173) ~[?:?]
    at com.mulesoft.agent.buffer.BufferedHandler.flushBuffer(BufferedHandler.java:241) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException: Remotely closed
    at org.asynchttpclient.exception.RemotelyClosedException.INSTANCE(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
INFO  2020-07-21 11:05:48,083 [pool-58-thread-2] [event: ] com.mulesoft.agent.buffer.BufferedHandler: Trying to retry flushing on buffer for EventTrackingSplunkInternalHandler. Remaining attempts: 0
```

Added below sections in log4j2 file

```
 <Http name="Splunk" url="http://xxxx-xxxxx-xxx:8088/services/collector/raw">
            <Property name="Authorization" value="Splunk e052f3fa-xxxxxxxxxx" ></Property>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p %c{1} [%t]: %m%n"></PatternLayout>
        </Http>
```

and

```
 <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Splunk" ></AppenderRef>
        </AsyncRoot>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error that you see is unrelated to sending logs from log4j2 to Splunk. You have followed the instructions from the link under title "Enabling Splunk on Server Group Using Anypoint Runtime Manager". That part of the article is for sending events from inside the application, through the Runtime Manager Agent to Splunk. That is completely separated from logging. Disable Splunk Event Tracking in Runtime Manager and the error should go away.

Comment: So wanted to know if i have to forward logs to splunk should i just update log4j2.xml. then what is the event tracking on runtime manager is for ?

Yes, i turned off the event tracking and the issue is gone , but i see below error messages in mule_agent file:

Post of application metrics for clientandaccount-migration failed with status 400
Could not publish app metrics for clientandaccount-migration to Ingest.
Some metrics for applications could not be published.
Buffer for IngestApplicationMonitorPublisher is configured to discard messages on flush failure. Discarding 1 messages.

Comment: You might have some other issue related to communication between the runtime manager agent and runtime manager. That's unrelated to logging but to internal metrics.
Runtime Manager can forward Business Events generated by Mule components in applications: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/business-events, that is also completely separated of logs